# Sorting HashMap String values using Java 8 Stream doesn't work

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I'm using the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java) question to sort the String values in a `LinkedHashMap`. However the sorting simply doesn't work. Here is the code I wrote.

```
Map<Integer, String> sortedMap = myMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry<Integer, String>::getKey, 
                    Map.Entry<Integer, String>::getValue));

myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>(sortedMap);
```

The weird thing is that it is sorting the `Integer`keys when both `comparingByValue` and `comparingByKey` methods are used. So it definitely is sorting, just not the `String` values but in both cases the `Integer` keys. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: My guess would be that `Collectors.toMap` is collecting them in a hash map, destroying the ordering.

Comment: That makes sense. However, that still doesn't explain the sorting of the Integer keys.

Comment: The integers seem sorted as the integer value itself is used as the hash, however as soon as you add more integers you might get a different order because of rehashing / multiple items ending up in the same bucket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `toMap` collector you are using put the elements in an `HashMap`, so sorting does not help here since you end up putting them in a non-ordered collection.

Use the overloaded `toMap` method, and supply a `LinkedHashMap` as concrete instance, i.e:

```
Map<Integer, String> sortedMap = 
     myMap.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                    (a, b) -> a, //or throw an exception
                                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Technically, it isn't specified what kind of map `toMap` will return. The current Oracle implementation indeed uses `HashMap`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have said "the implementation does not make any guarantee about the properties of the map and currently uses an HashMap behind the scenes. If you need a specific implementation use the overloaded `toMap` method."

Comment: @AlexisC. Sorry, what do yout thik about https://stackoverflow.com/q/61844376/811293

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that Collectors.toMap is collecting them in an unordered map, immediately destroying the ordering.

Try collecting them directly in a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Integer, String> sortedMap = myMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .collect((k, v) -> newMap.put(k, v));
myMap = newMap;
```

---

As for why the integer keys are sorted: this is probably mere coincidence, based on how the `HashMap` is bucketing the keys.